# How to Create new database and user only for the created database in mysql using Laravel 7?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, automation, laravel-7

I want to create a new database and user **only **for created new database And save it on current database.

Ex -

New User - Sam
Password - samDb123 (automatically generating)
database name- samDB (automatically generating)

current database :-

| UserName | database Name | password |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sam | samDB | samDb123 |
| max | maxDB | pws123 |

How to create a new database for a new user..

(I trying to access this data from anther Laravel system)

1. How to create a new database for a new user..

(I trying to access this data from anther Laravel system)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work.

create the database:

```
DB::getConnection()->statement('CREATE DATABASE :schema', array('schema' => 'sam'));
```

create db user:

```
DB::getConnection()->statement('CREATE USER :user@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY :password; array('user' => 'samDB', 'password' => 'samDb123'));
```

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::getConnection()

Comment: this didn't work for me.

Comment: try `DB::statement(` without `getConnection()`